# google map in fragment not moving to current location using fused location api

Tags: android, location, google-maps-api-2, fusedlocationproviderapi

i want to display current location on map, my map is in fragment and i'm using fused location provider in non activity class, but i'm not getting current location when the map is loaded, it is giving me current location only if i press mylocation button, but i want that when map is loaded it should show my current location not the world map.

locationprovide.java

```
public class LocationProvider implements
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        LocationListener {


    public interface LocationCallback {
        public void handleNewLocation(Location location);
    }



    public static final String TAG = LocationProvider.class.getSimpleName();

    /*
     * Define a request code to send to Google Play services
     * This code is returned in Activity.onActivityResult
     */
    private final static int CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;

    private LocationCallback mLocationCallback;
    private Context mContext;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

    public LocationProvider(Context context,LocationCallback locationCallback) {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
        mContext = context;
        mLocationCallback = locationCallback;

        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);



    }

    public void connect() {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    public void disconnect() {
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Location services connected.");


        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
        if (location == null) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
        }
        else {
            mLocationCallback.handleNewLocation(location);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        /*
         * Google Play services can resolve some errors it detects.
         * If the error has a resolution, try sending an Intent to
         * start a Google Play services activity that can resolve
         * error.
         */
        if (connectionResult.hasResolution() && mContext instanceof Activity) {
            try {
                Activity activity = (Activity)mContext;
                // Start an Activity that tries to resolve the error
                connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(activity, CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST);
            /*
             * Thrown if Google Play services canceled the original
             * PendingIntent
             */
            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                // Log the error
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            /*
             * If no resolution is available, display a dialog to the
             * user with the error.
             */
            Log.i(TAG, "Location services connection failed with code " + connectionResult.getErrorCode());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        mLocationCallback.handleNewLocation(location);
    }
}
```

**fragment**

```
public class ChildMapFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback,LocationProvider.LocationCallback  {

    private LocationProvider mLocationProvider;
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    Location mLastLocation;
    Marker mCurrLocationMarker;
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    Context mContext;
    String sid,cid;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_child_map, container, false);

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment)this.getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            checkLocationPermission();
        }else{
            mLocationProvider = new LocationProvider(mContext,this);


        }
        if (mLocationProvider!=null)
            mLocationProvider.connect();
        return view;

    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        if (mLocationProvider!=null)
            mLocationProvider.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        //Initialize Google Play Services
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                mLocationProvider = new LocationProvider(mContext,this);

                mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            }
        }
        else {

            mLocationProvider = new LocationProvider(mContext,this);

            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void handleNewLocation(Location location) {
        mLastLocation = location;
        if (mCurrLocationMarker != null) {
            mCurrLocationMarker.remove();
        }

        //Place current location marker
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        markerOptions.position(latLng);
        markerOptions.title("Current Position");
        markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA));
        mCurrLocationMarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

        //move map camera
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(11));


    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        mMap.clear();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (mLocationProvider!=null)
        mLocationProvider.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (mLocationProvider!=null)
        mLocationProvider.disconnect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        mContext=context;

    }

    public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION = 99;
    public boolean checkLocationPermission(){
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            // Asking user if explanation is needed
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale((Activity) mContext,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {

                // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
                // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
                // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

                //Prompt the user once explanation has been shown
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) mContext,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);


            } else {
                // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) mContext,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
            }
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           @NonNull String permissions[], @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION: {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    // permission was granted. Do the
                    // contacts-related task you need to do.
                    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext,
                            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                            mLocationProvider = new LocationProvider(mContext,this);

                        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                    }

                } else {

                    // Permission denied, Disable the functionality that depends on this permission.
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                return;
            }       
        }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just put the code below

```
if (mLocationProvider!=null){
     mLocationProvider.connect();
}
```

where you are using

mLocationProvider = new LocationProvider(mContext,this);